# css, jquery adjust line between draggable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have drawn a line that connects between draggable divs. But, as the div is being dragged, the line looses its source and destination point (i.e from one div to other div). What my objective is to set the line in such a way that it should not losses its edge from any div and where ever i drag the div it keeps updating itself dynamically that is height, rotation, position.

Sorry for bad english. Please help.....!
Here is my code

```js
var coordinates = function(element) {
  element = $(element);
  var top = element.position().top;
  var left = element.position().left;

  //--------------line------------------------------
  var length = Math.sqrt(((left) * (left)) + ((top) * (top)));
  var angle = Math.atan2(top, left) * 180 / Math.PI;
  var transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';

  $('#results').text('X: ' + left + ' ' + 'Y: ' + top).attr('style', 'margin-left:' + left + 'px');
  //$('#line1').attr('style', "margin-left:"+left+"px;margin-top:"+top+"px;height:"+(parseInt(100+top))+"px;transform:"+transform+";width:"+length+"px;");

  $('#line1').attr('style', "transform:" + transform + ";height:" + length + "px;");

}

//alert($('#box1').position().top);

$('#box1').draggable({
  start: function() {
    coordinates('#box1');
  },
  stop: function() {
    coordinates('#box1');
  }
});

$('#box2').draggable({
  start: function() {
    coordinates('#box2');
  },
  stop: function() {
    coordinates('#box2');
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.line {
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

#box1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#box2 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
}

#box3 {
  top: 250px;
  left: 200px;
}

#line1 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  /*transform: rotate(222deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(222deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(222deg);*/
}

#line2 {
  top: 220px;
  left: 150px;
  height: 115px;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>


<div class="line" id="line1"></div>


<div id="results">test</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you use canvas for this?

Comment: unfortunately no, i already offered to client for canvas or svg but he denied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you make your line an `svg` element, then you can manipulate the `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2` attributes of the line based on two boxes positions.

See example below:

```js
const $b1 = $("#box1");
const $b2 = $("#box2");
const $line = $("line");
const padding = 7;
const coordinates = function() {
  const x1 = $b1.offset().left + $b1.width()/2-padding;
  const y1 = $b1.offset().top + $b1.height()/2-padding;
  const x2 = $b2.offset().left + $b1.width()/2-padding;
  const y2 = $b2.offset().top + $b1.height()/2-padding;

  $line.attr("x1", x1);
  $line.attr("y1", y1);
  $line.attr("x2", x2);
  $line.attr("y2", y2);
}
coordinates();


$('#box1').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});

$('#box2').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}


#box1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#box2 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>

<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <line id="line" x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke: rgb(0,0,0); stroke-width:1" />
</svg>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

If you want to use a div instead of an svg, the same result can be achieved using the `createLine()` method you provided:

```js
const $b1 = $("#box1");
const $b2 = $("#box2");
const $line = $("#line");

const coordinates = function() {
  const x1 = $b1.offset().left + $b1.width()/2;
  const y1 = $b1.offset().top + $b1.height()/2;
  const x2 = $b2.offset().left + $b1.width()/2;
  const y2 = $b2.offset().top + $b1.height()/2;

  moveLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);  
}

coordinates();

function moveLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var length = Math.sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2)) + ((y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
    var transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';

    offsetX = (x1 > x2) ? x2 : x1;
    offsetY = (y1 > y2) ? y2 : y1;
    
    $line.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        '-webkit-transform': transform,
        '-moz-transform': transform,
        'transform': transform
      })
      .width(length)
      .offset({
        left: offsetX,
        top: offsetY
      });
}

$('#box1').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});

$('#box2').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#line1 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  /*transform: rotate(222deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(222deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(222deg);*/
}

.line {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; /* put line behind the boxes */
}


#box1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#box2 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>

<div class="line" id="line"></div>
   

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

For three boxes I suggest you add a `data-connect`attribute which specifies which boxes your line connects to. Then you can loop through each line and draw the lines connecting to each box:

```js
const coordinates = function() {

  $(".line").each(function() {
    const [box1, box2] = $(this).data("connect").split(',');
    const $b1 = $(box1);
    const $b2 = $(box2);
    
    const x1 = $b1.offset().left + $b1.width()/2;
    const y1 = $b1.offset().top + $b1.height()/2;
  
    const x2 = $b2.offset().left + $b2.width()/2;
    const y2 = $b2.offset().top + $b2.height()/2;

    moveLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, $(this)); 
  });

   
}

coordinates();

function moveLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, $line) {
    var length = Math.sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2)) + ((y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
    var angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
    var transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';

    var offsetX = (x1 > x2) ? x2 : x1;
    var offsetY = (y1 > y2) ? y2 : y1;
    
    $line.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        '-webkit-transform': transform,
        '-moz-transform': transform,
        'transform': transform
      })
      .width(length)
      .offset({
        left: offsetX,
        top: offsetY
      });
}

$('.box').draggable({
  drag: coordinates
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#line1 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  /*transform: rotate(222deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(222deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(222deg);*/
}

.line {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; /* put line behind the boxes */
}


#box1 {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#box2 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
}

#box3 {
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box1"></div>
<div class="box" id="box2"></div>
<div class="box" id="box3"></div>

<div class="line" id="line" data-connect="#box1,#box2"></div>
<div class="line" id="line2" data-connect="#box1,#box3"></div>
   

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: can u help me by adjusting this code with ur or mine code? instead of svg? i would be very thankful to you.

https://jsfiddle.net/zohaibrehman/qc69r3pf/8/

Comment: My this code works like that:

select the white are and then drag the mouse

Comment: @user3162878 hi, you can modify the createLine method to modify the css attribute of the current line. See edit above

Comment: hi can u help me how to form multiple lines from one to other multiple divs?

Comment: like that but everytime i looses something: 

https://jsfiddle.net/yfopets1/12/

Comment: thanks so dynamically if i would have to address N number of divs so i ve to do add these:

<div class="box" id="box4"></div>   and
<div class="line" id="line4" data-connect="#box1,#box4"></div>

?

Comment: @user3162878 yep, spot on

Comment: a small question is it possible to save the coordinates? somewhere so that when i re open up a page it shd stay at the same location?

Comment: @user3162878 yes, it is possible. Take a look at [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and storing the coords when the `stop` event occurs in the `draggable()` method

Comment: hi can you plz help me again in adjusting curve lines rather straight lines:

https://jsfiddle.net/zohaibrehman/6h9xovuL/7/

Comment: @user3162878 I suggest you ask this as a new question because I'm not too sure

Comment: hi once again. I am now allowed to work on svg. For that i ve created a curve:

Comment: can u help this time?

Comment: @NickParsons Hi Nick based on your answer I am creating a same kind of UI, can u please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64576551/tool-tip-in-html

Comment: @NickParsons instead of svg line I am using svg polyline